# Docker build,where to run?

Tags: docker

I am learning Docker

```
docker build -t mm/cowsay .
```

Should I go to `cowsay` folder or should I run it from my home `mm` directory?
I have registered on Docker hub.

Comment: You are using `.`, so go to where you have your `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker build` command follows instructions specified in a given Dockerfile, and outputs an image.

Syntax:

```
docker build \
  -t <tag-of-output-image> \
  -f <path-to-dockerfile>
```

If you use `.` instead of `-f <path-to-dockerfile>`, you are telling the Docker Engine to use the Dockerfile in the current directory.

So you need to run your command from where the Dockerfile exists.

Comment: In the Syntax you wrote you need to add the PATH